# Livescript, How to end a unnested callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, livescript

Reffering to: [http://livescript.net](http://livescript.net/)
Unnested callbacks and parentheses free chaining:
LiveScript

```
<-! $ 'h1' .on 'click'
alert 'boom!'
```

JavaScript

```
$('h1').on('click', function(){
  alert('boom!');
});
```

How can I write livescript like this in Javascript?

JavaScript

```
$('h1').on('click', function(){
  alert('boom!');
});
alert('out of callback');
```

Comment: search 'callback' in the livescript.net , and you can find what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. That's backcall.

You have two options : use a do (I don't think it makes sense)

```
do
  <- $ 'h1' .on 'click'
  alert 'boom!'
```

... Or just use a callback ?!

```
$ 'h1' .on 'click' ->
  alert 'boom'
```

Comment: Well, thx, now I'm using the second solution. and one more question , what's the difference between callback and backcall? :)

Comment: Callback is forward `->` and backcall is backward `<-`

Answer (score 1):

that worked for me @ Livescript 1.2.0

```
(
<- $ 'h1' .on 'click'
alert 'boom!'
)
(
<- $ 'h2' .on 'click'
alert 'kaboom!'
)
```

Enjoy)